# Sending Keys to webbrowser vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, button, browser, send, sendkeys

I have a webbrowser in my vb.net application and I would like to enter text into a textbox on a site. When button 1 is clicked, it programmatically finds the text box and types the message in.

```
Public Class Form1

        Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
            SendKeys.Send("{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}")
            SendKeys.Send("The text I want to send to the control.")
        End Sub

End Class
```

However, it doesn't work. The tab keys do get the curser in the right place but when the text is pasted in the application crashes. Whats gone wrong?

Comment: Are you using a windows forms app to navigate a webpage?

Comment: @StingyJack i suppose so, but you have confused me :/ i do not understand what you just said!

Comment: Your code is from a windows forms app. "Textbox on a site" implies that the target of your interaction is a web page. Is this correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using a webbrowser control, you can access the element by name.  For example, this will put text into Google's search box and then click the Google Search button:

```
WebBrowser1.Document.All("q").SetAttribute("Value", "Text value.")
WebBrowser1.Document.All("btnK").InvokeMember("click")
```

Answer (score 2):

To send keys to WebBrowser, get WebBrowser focus and later SendKeys. Use the following code:

```
 Me.WebBrowser1.Document.Body.Focus()
 System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.Send("...") 'Whatever keys combination you want
```